# Xamarin forms, App running on Visual Studio Android Emulator But crashes on real device

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have created an app,when build the app runs perfect on Visual Studio emulator. So I created release built and tried running the app on my physical android device. I am getting following error message on Device. I have used `Xam.plugin.media`

> android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity.InternalSetPage (Xamarin.Forms.Page page) [0x0006f] in :0 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity.SetMainPage () [0x0000c] in :0 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity.LoadApplication (Xamarin.Forms.Application application) [0x0025c] in :0 
>     at InterestMatch.Droid.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x00033] in <9e2a066af7c24de6828dc3a0f4e22d31>:0 
>     at Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentActivity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x0000f] in <1e89c43d3c7d48b5ba69bfc0b1bdf114>:0 
>     at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:6b534aff-3541-46f2-a92e-ac0022b9c4a7 (intptr,intptr,intptr)
>       at md5ed93386354f0e17f050b2885712023ca.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
>       at md5ed93386354f0e17f050b2885712023ca.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
>       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6303)
>       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2402)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2509)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:153)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5523)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)

Here is my code

**MainActivity.cs**

```
public class MainActivity global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;



        Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = this;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }



    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

}
```

**app.xaml.cs**

```
     using InterestMatch.Inter;
     using InterestMatch.Models;
     using System;
     using System.Collections.Generic;
     using System.Linq;
     using System.Text;
     using Xamarin.Auth;
     using Xamarin.Forms;

     namespace InterestM
     {
     public partial class App : Application
{

    public static string AppName { get { return "StoreAccountInfoApp"; } }

    public static ICredentialsService CredentialsService { get; private set; }

    public App ()
    {                      
         var account = AccountStore.Create().FindAccountsForService(App.AppName).FirstOrDefault();

         CredentialsService = new CredentialsService();

        if (CredentialsService.DoCredentialsExist())
        {
            InitializeComponent();               
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new InterestM.MainMenu(account.Username.ToString()));
        }
        else
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new InterestM.Accounts.Login());
        }

    }

    protected override void OnStart ()
    {
        // Handle when your app starts
    }

    protected override void OnSleep ()
    {
        // Handle when your app sleeps
    }

    protected override void OnResume ()
    {
        // Handle when your app resumes
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you show us your App.xaml.cs ?

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe I have added app.xaml.cs file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing Android project options fixed the issue for me.

Open your Android project's Properties. Go to Android Options. Change Linking property to **"Sdk Assemblies Only"**.